# Xamarin Adding Semi-Const Headers to Refit API Call

Tags: xamarin, refit

[Updated]

Thanks to jason in the comments I was able to find the solution. You can supply a new httpClient when creating the rest service which will take a client handler. In the client handler overwrite the SendAsync method and add the request headers you want for each call there. Code below.

HttpClientHandler

```
class AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler : HttpClientHandler
{

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("platform", Constants.platform);
        request.Headers.Add("build", "72");
        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", Constants.platform + " RELEASE");

        return await base.SendAsync(request,cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Client creation

```
authenticationAPI = RestService.For<IAuthenticationAPI>(new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler()) { BaseAddress = new Uri(Constants.RestUrl) });
```

[Question]
I want to add the platform to my refit API calls in the header but I don't want to have to pass it in with the method call. Is there a way to add header that is created at runtime to all API calls? I tried this but it doesn't work since it's not a constant.

```
[Headers("Content-Type: application/json", Constants.platformHeader)]
```

Separate Constants class

```
public static string platform = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android? "android" : "iOS";
public const string platformHeader = "platform: " + platform;
```

Comment: see the [docs](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit#authorization-dynamic-headers-redux).  The example they use is for auth, but you can apply it to any header value

Comment: Yessir that is how do it. Just started refit today and didn't see this in the docs. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Ubarjohade If has solved that , remember to update the solution in answer when you have time . This will be helpful for others to know how to solve that :-)